# C++ int main(int argc, char* argv[])

Tags: c++, argv, argc

how do i save int argc, char* argv in to int someting.

i am trying to get the arguments from a test program and save it into int ****;

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
 int limit = argc;
 cout<< limit <<endl;
 for (int candidate = 2; candidate < limit; candidate++) {
    int total = 1;
    for (int factor = 2; factor * factor < candidate; factor++) {
        if (candidate % factor == 0)
            total += factor + candidate / factor;

    }
    if (total == candidate) {
        cout << candidate << ' ';
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

and the program is pre-set the arguments is 100, and it just can't save in to `int limit`

Comment: it is looking for  the Perfect Numbers the arguments is 100 and it need to print 6, 28

Comment: Read about [main function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function): the `argc` is the number of arguments passed to the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        cerr << "Not enough arguments\n";
        return -1;
    }
    int limit = atoi(argv[1]); // convert first argument to integer
    ...
```

Comment: thanks for ans the question, in the note it is using (const int limit = argc > 1 ? atoi(argv[1]) : 1000;) what is the different

Comment: `atoi` is possibly not the best choice due to lack of error handling

Comment: @PooPo Can you not follow the logic? `argc` is the number of arguments given to the program. In my version if there are not enough arguments I print an error message and quit. In your version if there are not enough arguments a default value of 1000 is used.